# What is an example of arithmetic and buffer overflows in a php application?

Tags: php, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to find evidence whether it is possible to have overflows in a php application, whether buffer overflows or arithmetic overflows.

I believe it's possible to have these overflows in the core php software, but this question is about overflows in an application written in php.

Comment: What's a "php overflow"? Did you mean "arithmetic overflow"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Arithmetic Overflow**

You cannot have arithmetic overflows in PHP, at least not in the sense that the number wraps around, leading to a smaller result than expected (which is the kind that may have security implications).

There are two reasons for this:

- if an integer is increased above its limit, it is automatically converted to float.
- if a float is increased above its limit, it is automatically set to INF, which is treated as the largest value.

You can try this yourself:

```
$max = PHP_INT_MAX;
var_dump($max);         // int 9223372036854775807
$max = PHP_INT_MAX + 1; 
var_dump($max);         // float 9.2233720368548E+18

$max_float = 1.8e307;
var_dump($max_float);   // float 1.8E+307
$max_float = 1.8e307 * 10;
var_dump($max_float);   // float INF
```

It works the same way for negative numbers.

But even though you do not have an overflow of integers in the traditional sense, you still might run into problems. Consider for example these cases:

```
PHP_INT_MAX < (PHP_INT_MAX + 1) // -> false
PHP_INT_MAX == (PHP_INT_MAX + 1) // -> true
```

**Arithmetic Underflow**

You can have underflows in PHP:

```
$min_float = 9.8813129168249E-324;
var_dump($min_float);   // float 9.8813129168249E-324
$min_float = 9.8813129168249E-324 / 10;
var_dump($min_float);   // float 0
```

As `0` is equal to a number of things, among them `NULL`, `false`, `"0"`, `"foobar"`, this may cause problems in some situations. But these problems aren't really a result of the underflow.

**Buffer Overflow**

Buffer Overflows in PHP may exist because of vulnerabilities in PHP itself, but not because of application code.

Here is a list of some [buffer overflow vulnerabilities in PHP](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/cvssscoremin-9/cvssscoremax-/PHP-PHP.html).

Comment: Of course, once you've hit the point where an `int` morphs into a `float`, you can no longer use it as a simple counter, and you are in a situation where N+1==N. Arguably that's a type of overflow, with a limit instead of wrapping - like trying to add water to a full bucket.

Comment: @PhilLello thanks, I updates my answer. `<` is also not working as expected.

Comment: tim - should the variable in the final code block be `$min_float` and not `$max_float`? If not, I'm confused by that code block.